# Excel VBA - If statement returning false returns #value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a bigger Excel Macro, but have simplified my code a bit and found what my issue is. In the if statement below, I can change the rng to a cell that makes the statement true, and it works fine. But if I change it to a cell (or a cell within a range) that will return false, it returns the #value error. I'm pretty new to VBA, so what am I doing wrong?

```
Function count_same(column As Range, row As Range)

Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim result As Long
result = 0

Set rng = Worksheets("Install together 2").Range("f10")

For Each cell In rng.Cells

If WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(WorksheetFunction.Search(row.Value, cell.Value)) Then
    result = result + 1
End If

Next cell

count_same = result

End Function
```

Comment: can you provide a working and non working example, a cell is a range object.

Comment: The one above is working, because cell f10 contains a match of what I'm searching for. But if I change that range to f11, or even "f10:f11", it throws #value because f11 does not contain what I'm searching for. I'd just like it to skip over f11 if it does not contain the text.

Comment: Try this instead. `if instr(1,cell,row) > 0 then`

Comment: Why would he need to skip an error? That would be terribly poor advice for a new programmer. `On Error Resume Next` should be avoided unless absolutely neccesary.

Comment: From MSDN, regarding the SEARCH method: "If find_text is not found, the #VALUE! error value is returned."  You might have to wrap it in an IfError method to get what you want, or rewrite in a different way.  Can you reword what you're trying to achieve with this?

Comment: @Zerk Agreed. Deleted the comment.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I think using an IfError can work. When you use the "IsNumber(Search" function in a worksheet, it just returned false. Didn't even think about search returning a #Value inside of that. I can modify with ifError to fix it. Appreciate the help!

Comment: @thuetten See my example below. Don't use IfError (which is intended for dealing with errors within the worksheet). Use `IsError` which is an inbuilt VBA function. It will also be ideal for you to learn how to write VBA without using `WorksheetFunction` since usually you will take a performance and maintanability hit by relying on Worksheetfunctions over VBA Functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this instead of my previous answer. If I understand your needs correctly, this should do the trick. It takes an input range (that you want to search through), and an inputrange with the searchvalue. It then returns the instances of that substring within the input range.

At the top of the code I have included Application.Volatile which forces it to recalculate when the sheet changes. You can comment this out.

```
Function count_same(InputRange As Range, RowValue As Range, ColValue as Range)
    Application.Volatile

    Dim result As Long
    result = 0

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In InputRange.Cells
        If InStr(1, RowValue.Value, cell.Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 And InStr(1, ColValue.Value, cell.Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            result = result + 1
        End If
    Next cell

    count_same = result
End Function
```

Comment: @thuetten Let me know if the above code works for this. If I understand you correctly, the above code should work as needed.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. I'll look more into VBA functions in the future instead of forcing it to use worksheet functions. Thanks so much for all of your help!

Comment: Not a problem. VBA is easy to learn once you get a handle on it. Play around and see what you can come up with. you'll be surprised what you can do :).

Answer (score 0):

you can use on error resume next and put some error checking in. you also have column as Range but don't ever use it in the method so you can remove it.

```
Public Function count_same(row As Range)
On Error Resume Next
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim result As Long
result = 0

Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Install together 2").Range("F10")

For Each cell In rng.Cells

    If WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(WorksheetFunction.Search(row.Value, cell.Value)) Then
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Err.Clear
        Else
            result = result + 1
        End If
    End If

Next cell

count_same = result

End Function
```

Comment: This does work, thank you. And I did have a column range in there, but removed when I was troubleshooting and couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Function count_same(column As Range, row As Range)

Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim result As Long
result = 0

Set rng = Worksheets("Install together 2").Range("f10")

For Each cell In rng.Cells
    If Not IsError(WorksheetFunction.Search(Row.Value, cell.Value)) Then
        If WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(WorksheetFunction.Search(row.Value, cell.Value)) Then
            result = result + 1
        End If
    End If

Next cell

count_same = result

End Function
```

The practice to learn from this is that we can anticipate a potential error. What we then do is check the inverse of the IsError function. IsError will return TRUE if it is an error. We only want to run the Worksheet function if it isnt an error. By doing `If Not IsError` we are effectively saying 'If this is not an error then'.

As you learn VBA, try to prevent errors instead of using `On Error Resume Next`, or `GoTo` since these work well enough when you're getting started, but become impossible to use when you get further along (and you'll curse yourself every time you see a GoTo or an On Error statement).

Comment: So for a range "f11", where it should not find a match, it returns 0 like it should. But if I change it back to "f10" where it should find a match and return 1, it is also returning 0.

Comment: Just kidding, I re-copied in your suggestion above and it's back to how it was. Returning 1 when it should, but still giving #value for when it should be 0.

Comment: I am having a hard time figuring out what your code is supposed to do exactly. I also just noticed that you have the user input Column, but it is never used. What task are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: So I did have a column range in, but when it wasn't working I took it out to simplify to troubleshoot. I have a column of cells with multiple names in it, separated by a semicolon. My end goal is to see how many times one name appears with the other - So pass it a name (row) and another name (column), and if it finds the row name and the column name in the cell, it adds 1 to result. This is just a first step to get there

Comment: Is the column range the range you actually want to search through? Where rng in the code above is a placeholder?

Comment: Here is a worksheet function that does what I need to: =IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2,'Install together 2'!F29)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1,'Install together 2'!F29))),1,0). However, this function only searches one cell at a time. I need to search a range (rng) of f2:f81

Comment: In that above comment, A2 would be my row value and B1 would be my column value. The column I want to search through will be rng, which is f2:f81

Comment: So you want to make sure the substring is in both Column and Row? See my new answer below. This account for the AND statement, and only increments if both Row, and Col, contain the substring. It also adds a parameter for an InputRange (instead of hardcoding the rng variable).

Comment: I want to see how many times the single name in the column and the single name in the row appear in the same cell in that range of 80 cells. Sorry, it's kind of hard to explain.

Comment: So lets say the cell value is "Tom" and Row contains "Tom" and Column contains "Charles" you want to return 0, but if Row contains "Tom" and the Column contains "Tom" then you want to return 1? Ill modify my below answer for that.